# c# webservice, Disco.exe not generating .xsd file

Tags: c#, web-services, xsd

I am trying to generate xsd schema for my test webservice(simple webservice having an Add function taking two params), I am using disco.exe which is generating discomap,disco and wsdl files but no XSD. How can I generate XSD file and how to use it for validating schema when consuming the webservice.

Comment: From what it sounds like, you seem to have an XML Schema embedded within the types section of your WSDL file; and you want something that will automatically extract the XSD content within the WSDL file into a standalone XSD file that you can then use to validate XML. Is this correct?

Comment: wsdl generated by DISCO.exe contains schema as well , I am wondering why disco.exe not generating schema in seperate xsd file

Comment: DISCO will not rewrite WSDL/XSD files; it'll DISCOver them, by resolving references (WSDL imports, XSD includes/imports). It means that the original WSDL was authored the way you see it. I can answer you how to automate the extraction of the XSD(s) within the WSDL types section, if you confirm that indeed this is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

the wsdl is sufficient as it contains the schemas within. Why would you need to convert is to an xsd?

If you really want to do it like that use wsdl.exe / svcutil.exe to turn the wsdl into c# classes and turn them back to xsd with xsd.exe.

Comment: I want to validate xsd schema, i.e. if a mandatory field is missing service should throw appropriate exception , can i turn on xsd validation on wsdl?

Answer (score 0):

use svcutil.exe to generate schemas